# Probability - Given some conditions

Tags: probability

I am having trouble with the following question:

> A torch will last at least $500$ hours from new with probability $0.6$. If it lasts
>   this long, it survives the next $500$ hours with probability $0.4$, and if it lasts
>   $1000$ hours, the probability that it will fail within the next $500$ hours is $0.9$.
>   What is the probability that the torch will last at least 1500 hours?

So I want to find $P(\text{torch last at least } 1500 \text{ hours})$. 
Since there are some conditional probabilities there, I know that I should be using either the multiplication rule or the total law of probability - but I am not sure which. I think that I should use the multiplication rule as it seems to make sense to AND all the events and have that results.

Looking at this again,  I think that the law of total probability is applicable, but I would need to partition the sample space - but I'm not sure how to do this.

Any help and advice? I'm pretty confused.

Comment: You can directly calculate the probability that it lasts at least $1000$ hours, from which you can subtract the probability it lasts between $1000$ and $1500$ hours.

Comment: The comment doesn't match your (correct) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the probabilities given after the first period are conditional to having survived thus far, you can just multiply $0.6\times0.4\times(1-0.9)$